# How to use multiple locations for configSource in config file for WCF Client

Tags: wcf, binding, config, configsection, configsource

Our application will act as client for different WCF-services in the future. At the moment we consume only one WCF-Service. Our config-file for the application is set up using configSource-attribues at the moment:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services configSource="services.config"/>
    <bindings configSource="bindings.config"/>
    <behaviors configSource="behaviors.config"/>
    <extensions configSource="extensions.config"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to use multiple files for e.g. the bindings section? We would like to have each binding for a particular WCF-service that we consume in one file. So we would need to point the bindings section to multiple configSources.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can't separate the configsections into different physical files. So we ended up merging e.g. all bindings in one file.

Comment: Do you mean that all of the sections `<services>`, `<bindings>`, `<behaviors>`, and `<extensions>` now have `configSource='serviceModel.config'` attribute? Can you copy/paste the working example in your answer please? It would be a huge help for us. Thank you.